# Default file manager

Tags: unity, nautilus, filemanager, default-programs, file-association

Recently I changed my default file manager to Krusader and it seems that my computer crashes constantly; How does I change it back to Nautilus?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply uninstall Krusader, and if Nautilus is the only file manager left, Ubuntu will automatically set it as the default file manager.